# Regex to check for AND

Tags: regex

I am trying to check whether a string starts from a particular word And also a particular substring occurs in it.

So lets say if I have a string like this:

`SCSI\DISK&VEN_MICRON&PROD_1100\4&2096297&0&000200`

I need to check whether this string has `4&2096297&0` and also it starts from `SCSI`

**I did this** : `(^SCSI|\\4&2096297&0)` . This is pretty much doing the work but it is also selecting the substring even if the string doesn't start from `SCSI`

Regex101 : [Attempt](https://regex101.com/r/xV0tHI/3)

It is working as expected but the problem is it is selecting a substring even if the string doesn't start from `SCSI`.

Is it possible to  put a AND condition to it.

Comment: Try `\bSCSI\S*?\\4&2096297&0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to alternate with `|` - that will fulfill the regex if the left side *or* the right side of the `|` matches. You want to check that *both* conditions match. After the beginning of the string and `SCSI`, try repeating characters until you get to `4&2096297&0`:

```
^SCSI.*4&2096297&0
```

https://regex101.com/r/xV0tHI/4

If you want to capture the already-hard-coded `SCSI` and `4&2096297&0`, then put parentheses around them:

```
^(SCSI).*(4&2096297&0)
```

Comment: Can I get this in two matches. Like two separate green Highlights instead of a single one

Comment: What do you mean, in two matches? Do you mean you want captured groups? If so, there's not much point, because they're already hard-coded into the regex, I would think?

Comment: You are right but the thing is I want to get `4&2096297&0` this group only if a String start from `SCSI` not `XYZ` and not `SCSII`

Comment: If you want to match whether the string *starts* with `SCSI` *and* contains that substring, then any match *will necessarily include* that substring as a group, if you put it in a captured group as in the edit to the answer. If the string starts with XYZ, for example, the regex won't match at all.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am achieving. But why `4&2096297&0` is in red and not in green. Also, sorry if this is a stupid question but can I remove the full match

Comment: Do you mean you want the substrings to be *combined*, like something that results in `SCSI4&2096297&0`? That's not possible with regex alone unless you use something like *replace* that cuts out the middle of the string. It's not clear at all what you're asking for at this point.

Comment: Ok just to clear the confusion. If you my link. You can see 2 matches. But in your solution I have 1 match with 2 groups. My question is can I get 2 matches. with single group.

Comment: No, that's not possible unless you do something like `replace` in whatever language you're working with, which strips out the middle of the matches first. A capturing group cannot span over multiple parts of the string.

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha You could do this as long as your regex flavor supports some features. Try [`(?|(^SCSI\\)|\G(?!^)(?:(\\4&2096297&0)\S*|\S))`](https://regex101.com/r/KKcBo7/1)

Comment: Or using `J` flag if available: `(?<S>^SCSI\\)\S*?(?<S>\\4&2096297&0)`.

Comment: Besides, what is the reason behind capturing two strings that you already know them?

Comment: @revo Basically the string are coming from the server and this is the id `4&2096297&0` we want to filter out if it starts from `SCSI`. Though this could be done with python itself but I want to use regex just as an alternative